# Mocking global modules multiple times in the same file with Vitest

Tags: unit-testing, vitest

I want to mock a method from a global module multiple times within the same test file. Specifically, I want to be able to change `process.cwd()` on the fly.

I can mock the return value (with other limitations) using the `mock` method. Something like this:

```js
import process from 'process';

vi.mock('process', async () => {
  const process = vi.importActual('process');
  // Dynamically import libraries (because `mock` is hoisted)
  const { __dirname } = await import('...');
  const cwd = () => path.join(__dirname(import.meta.url), '...');
  return { default: { ...process, cwd } };
});

describe('testName', () => {
  it('... ', async () => {
    console.log(process.cwd()) // => proper mock value
  })
})
```

I've tried using [`doMock`](https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-dounmock) in `beforeEach` and also directly inside the `describe` callback. Neither worked as desired.

I'm also restoring the mocks automatically after each test.

```js
// vitest.config.js
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    restoreMocks: true,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing the process dynamically in every `it` after mocking it in `beforeEach`?

```js
vi.doMock('process', async () => {
  const process = vi.importActual('process');
  // Dynamically import libraries (because `mock` is hoisted)
  const { __dirname } = await import('...');
  const cwd = () => path.join(__dirname(import.meta.url), '...');
  return { default: { ...process, cwd } };
});
const {default: process } = await import('process');
```